# Spring cloud config server with AWS S3 backend not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-config

I have a simple application, where I am creating a config server with S3 backend.

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: awss3
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        awss3:
          bucket: bucket-config
          region: "eu-central-1"
          order: 1
```

pom.xml

```
       <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.79</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The config server starts up, but when I try to use a config client to fetch the config from the config server, it does not fetch anything.

I used the same client to fetch config when the config server is configured with git and it is able to fetch the config.
Now when I am trying to use AWS S3, the client does not get the config.

In the documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend), It says credentials are loaded using eDefault AWS Credential Provider Chain. So I just specified the `AWS_PROFILE` environment property to connect to AWS while running the application in my IDE.

Does anyone know if there is something I am missing?

Comment: add debug=true and share us the log

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?